# java OutOfMemoryError exception and Metaspace error while multiple users are login in the application

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

In my application while multiple users, at least **10 users**, are login in from different locations at the same time, the application is showing **2 errors** :-

1) the **OutOfMemoryError** exception (heap space/ GC error)
and,

2) the **Metaspace error** (in jdk-8 environment).

For your information, the application is running on 64-bit windows 7 system and is using jdk-8 environment.
The jvm parameters are set to 1.5Gb in the environment, like below:-

**-XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1512m**

I need 2 guidance:

*1) Please suggest a solution to solve the GC problem, so that **Any number of Users** can access the application at the same time.*

*2) Also please provide a **Concept** on how to solve metaspace error and how to increase the default metaspace size of the application.*

Thanks.

Comment: edited as per suggestion.

Comment: Please cancel the down-vote, or my account could be blocked. I will validate in the future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Classes and classes metadata get stored in the Metaspace
- Static as well as dynamically loaded classes
- Metaspace is not part of the Java heap and is allocated out of native
  memory

**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace**

- Metaspace by default is unlimited
- MaxMetaspaceSize : This exception
  means that the Metaspace is full with the loaded classes and their
  metadata, and the application is requesting to load more classes The
  JVM has already invoked Full GC but could not free up any space in
  the Metaspace

  - Indicates: the Metaspace is sized smaller than the
    footprint of classes and its metadata, or the application is
    unintentionally holding on to some set of classes in the Metaspace

Try to increase the heap size memory by invoking following option

```
-Xmx
```

If you want to increase the Metaspacesize, invoke the following option.

```
-XX:MetaspaceSize=m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=n
```

Comment: Thanks.
Please guide where to invoke the above Metaspacesize. 
Do I need to set it up under the **JAVA_OPTS** environment variable, where the **MaxPermSize** is declared?
Can I declare it as 1024m?

Comment: exactly, you have to declare in the **JAVA_OPTS** environment variable. The size should be 1/4th of the JVM heap size.                            Consider the below example:                                               
    `set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -
    XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256M"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: As you say “*Metaspace by default is unlimited*”, so another way to increase the Metaspacesize is *to remove that option*.